How do I apply the Enumerations for the Word object model using the Enumerations list?
I'm new to VBA in the sense that I'm learning how to use the object model correctly, instead of just recording macros and doing a mediocre job.
I have a series of .RTF documents that are generated from an engineering program and the only file type for output is .RTF.  In those RTF files are images that I need to resize before incorporating them into a report.  I have a macro that resizes all of the images, and I want to save the document in a new format.  For now, I'm using the Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show statement to open a file dialog so that I can change the file format to .docx.
Obviously, this would be better if I can automate this, because I have more than a couple of files.  But, there's no point in automating it until I can figure out how to use the wdFormatDocumentDefault enumeration.
I did some searching and I can't get the example enums that I found to work as described.
So my basic question is, what is the syntax to make these enumerations work?  Do I need to use ActiveDocument.SaveAs2?  If I do that, do I have to specify the file name?  Can I just keep the same file name, but change the file type so that the .RTF file becomes a .docx file?
I modified this from another post on the Stack, but I'm getting a syntax error.
Original:
docx.SaveAs2(fileName, MSWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault)
Modified:
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(ActiveDocument.Name, MSWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault)
I don't understand why the modified code doesn't work.
EDIT:
I figured out that I need to specify the enumerations like this:
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
So, at least the code runs, but it doesn't actually save the file as a .docx file type.
I was partially referencing other tips and trying things out on my own.  I removed the .RTF file extension from the file name, and then added the FileFormat enum.
Working solution is this:
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 _
    FileName:=Left(ActiveDocument.Name, Len(ActiveDocument.Name) - 4), _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault

Suggested improvements are welcome.

There are several different things going on in your experimental code.
In here
docx.SaveAs2(fileName, MSWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault)


At some point before executing this line, you need to have set the
variable docx to the Document object you want to save (e.g.
ActiveDocument or ThisDocument), e.g. using
Set docx = ActiveDocument

If you want to use the "fully qualified" name for
wdFormatDocumentDefault, you need
Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault (i.e. Word rather than
MSWord). That was probably what caused a syntax error in your first two examples.

I don't think The wdFormatDocumentDefault option does what the documentation says it does. Hence the post by @taller. In any case, however you specify one of the standard Word zipped formats .docx, .docm, .dotx, .dotm, Word should save the document with the internal format that corresponds to the chosen exteension/format. ISTR this is regarded as a security feature.


To expand on some of these things...
Displaying the Immediate Window (View->Immediate WIndow) in the VB Editor makes it easy to check some things by entering them in the Window and taking advantage of VBE's Intellisense to pop up available options.
e.g. if you enter
?MSWord.

you won't see any suggestions, which is a clue that MSWord has no special meaning, whereas entering
?Word.

should bring up a list of all the things you could put after the dot.
The ? in that command is essentially the same as using Debug.Print in a SUb/Function in a code module.
Typically, the examples of VBA code you'll find on the Internet do not use the fully qualified enum names. Since Word recognises all the wd enum names without qualification anyway, a lot of the time people leave them unqualified. You have to be more careful when using these constants in, say, VBA code to be run from Excel. In that case you either have to make a reference to the WOrd object, or use the actual value of the constant (16 in the case of wdFormatDocumentDefault), or make your own definition and use that. In code written in a more modern programming environment, say .NET, you are much more likely to see the fully qualified name. In any case, it is advisable in VBA to put the  directive
Option Explicit

at the top of every Module, because the compiler then detects undeclared and variables and constant names (e.g. it will detect some misspellings).
The syntax you worked out here:
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault

is fine, but is one of several ways you could have specified that. e.g. You could have used positional parameters like this
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 , wdFormatDocumentDefault

NB, you can tell that the FileName parameter is optional by opening View->Object Browser, searching for WOrd's .SaveAs2 method, and looking at the Method signature, which shows
SaveAs2([FileName],[SaveFormat],...,)

The [] mean the parameter is syntactically optional. You may find there are cases where at runtime you have to provide a value. The fact that no data type is given means the parameter is a Variant, which usually means that you can pass several different types of thing to the Method.

Thank you for the thorough explanation and the teaching.  I will need to review this several times, but I am very grateful for the effort you put into the response.  I am already using Option Explicit to make sure that I catch myself when using variables I haven't defined yet.
What is a positional parameter?  I see the differences in your ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 statement, but I don't understand why the second one is works.
Great tip on the immediate window.
Where/How do you find the references that show you how to specify the parameters for a method?

@gshockxcc You can find out a lot about the classes, class members (properties, methods, functions, events) and method/function parameters using the VBE View->Object Browser. Better if you explore it a bit, but when you select a Method/Function, its signature (parameter names, types,,sequence, and result type are shown at the bottom of the Window. That doesn't always tell you what the parameters "mean", but you can usually get more info. At Microsoft's site (e.g. do a web search for "Microsoft Word VBA Document.SaveAs2".

@gshockxcc When the method/function signature is, e.g. myroutine(a,b,c) and you want t all it using a set to 3, b set to "abc" and c set to 3.75), then you can provide the parameters positionally, i.e. in the sequence they appear in the signature, e.g. call myroutine(3,"abc",3.75).In that case, if say b is optional and you don't want to provide it, you can use call myroutine(3,,3.75). With named parameters, you can omit any optional parameters and just provide the ones you want in any sequence using e.g. c:=3.75, a:=3. Some mixtures are allowed, but arguably best avoided.


There are several ways to get the new file name (.docx). String function (eg. Left) in OP is good too.
Using the full path on SaveAs2 method is more reliable.

Sub Macro1()
    Dim sPath As String, aTxt
    With ActiveDocument
        sPath = .Path & "\"
        aTxt = Split(.Name, ".")
        aTxt(UBound(aTxt)) = "docx"
        .SaveAs2 FileName:=sPath & Join(aTxt, "."), FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
End Sub


Great tip.  Thank you.  I didn't even know that I could get the path using ".Path".
I don't understand why "aTxt" works at the end of the Dim statement.  Does VBA treat that as a variant if not defined as a type?

Yes, it is a variant.

I'm working on implementing the suggestion you posted above, but I don't follow what the 'sFn' is used for.  I follow what you're doing with sPath and aTxt, but I don't see where sFn is used.  Sorry for my ignorance.

sFn isn't used in the snippet. I've updated the answer.
